# Output error when PHP excute shell to run Ansible with 2-byte-characters hostname

Tags: php, ansible, sh

I am using PHP to excute Ansible command on Centos 7

Here are simple code inside test.php file

```
<?php
$command = "./run_ansible.sh";
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

and shell script

```
ANSIBLE_DIR="/etc/ansible"
ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_FILE="${ANSIBLE_DIR}/inventories/production"
COMMAND="ansible all -i ${ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_FILE} -l 北京,广州 -m ping"
sudo ${COMMAND}
```

> 

When I run php file on Server, it worked

```
php test.php

广州 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
北京 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

When I run php file on Web Browser through URL (http://url/test.php), it failed

```
?? | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
?? | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

> 

The hostname is changed to ??

Any idea on this case ?

Comment: have you specify UTF-8 encodage on your html header ?

Comment: @Yanis-git : do you mean this one "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ? I tried it and it still failed

Comment: i mean `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: @Yanis-git Yes I did it.

Comment: is really looks like encodage issue.

Comment: you could try to check if your php can `echo` those hostnames (北京,广州) on your browser, to rule out the possibility of character encoding problems. Also, you could have the php script write this output to a file, and see if the `??` appear there too. it will help you understand where the problem comes up.

Comment: @ilias-sp In php, I can echo those hostnames on browser. 
When I use "cat, echo" command in shell, PHP can display those hostnames. But if I use "ansible" command, the output will be failed on browser (it displays ??)

Answer (score 0):

Try with exec:

```
exec("./run_ansible.sh");
```

And give the full path like:

```
exec("./var/www/html/run_ansible.sh");
```

And set your file encoding to utf-8

Comment: Thanks for your recommandation. I just tried and it still failed :(

Answer (score 0):

When I use "cat, echo" command in shell, PHP can display those hostnames. But if I use "ansible" command, the output will be failed on browser (it displays ??)

Does anyone have idea for this case ?